# About using an array of functions in Perl

Tags: perl, arrays, function, scope, concept

We are trying to build an API to support commit() and rollback() automatically, so that we don't have to bother with it anymore. By researching, we have found that using `eval {}` is the way to go.

For `eval {}` to know what to do, I have thought of giving the API an array of functions, which it can execute with a `foreach` without the API having to intepret anything. However, this function might be in a different package.

Let me clarify with an example:

```
sub handler {
    use OSA::SQL;
    use OSA::ourAPI;
    my @functions = ();
    push(@functions, OSA::SQL->add_page($date, $stuff, $foo, $bar));
    my $API = OSA::ourAPI->connect();
    $API->exec_multi(@functions);
}
```

The question is: Is it possible to execute the functions in `@functions` inside of `OSA::ourAPI`, even if ourAPI has no `use OSA::SQL`. If not, would it be possible if I use an array reference instead of an array, given that the pointer would point to the known function inside of the memory?

Note: This is the basic idea that we want to base the more complex final version on.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "execute the given functions inside of OSA::ourAPI".

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. The functions inside of @functions are the ones I am talking about.

Comment: `eval` is rarely the way to go... and putting a `use` statement inside a method will not delay its execution to when the method is run. It is executed immediately when the file is parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

- You are NOT adding a function pointer to your array. You are adding teh return value of calling the add_page() subroutine. You have 3 solutions to this:

  A. You will need to store (in `@functions`) an array of arrayrefs of the form `[\&OSA::SQL::add_page, @argument_values]`, meaning you pass in an actual reference to a subroutine (called statically); and then exec_multi will do something like (syntax may not be 100% correct as it's 4am here)

  ```
  sub exec_multi {
      my ($class, $funcs)= @_;
      foreach my $f (@$funcs) {
          my ($func, @args) = @$f;
          my $res = &$func(@args);
          print "RES:$res\n";
      }
  }
  ```

  Just to re-iterate, this will call individual subs in static version (`OSA::SQL::add_page`), e.g. WITHOUT passing the package name as the first parameter as a class call `OSA::SQL->add_page` would. If you want the latter, see the next solution.

  ---

  B. If you want to call your subs in class context (like in your example, in other words with the class name as a first parameter), you can use ysth's suggestion in the comment.

  You will need to store (in `@functions`) an array of arrayrefs of the form `[sub { OSA::SQL->add_page(@argument_values) }]`, meaning you pass in a reference to a subroutine which will in turn call what you need; and then exec_multi will do something like (syntax may not be 100% correct as it's 4am here)

  ```
  sub exec_multi {
      my ($class, $funcs)= @_;
      foreach my $f (@$funcs) {
          my ($func) = @$f;
          my $res = &$func();
          print "RES:$res\n";
      }
  }
  ```

  ---

  C.   You will need to store (in `@functions`) an array of arrayrefs of the form `[ "OSA::SQL", "add_page", @argument_values]`, meaning you pass in a package and function name; and then exec_multi will do something like (syntax may not be 100% correct as it's 4am here)

  ```
  my ($package, $sub, @args) = @{ $functions[$i] };
  no strict 'refs';
  $package->$sub(@args);
  use strict 'refs';
  ```

---

- If I understood your question correctly, then you don't need to worry about whether ourAPI uses OSA::SQL, since your main code imports it already.

  However, since - in #1B - you will be passing a list of packages to exec_multi as first elements of each arrayref, you can do "`require $package; $package->import();`" in exec_multi. But again, it's completely un-necessary if your handler call already required and loaded each of those packages. And to do it right you need to pass in a list of parameters to `import()` as well. BUT WHYYYYYY? :)

Comment: `use $package;` is not legal.  you can translate a module name to a relative pathname of a .pm file and then use `require` though.

Better to have @functions just store coderefs, so:  `push @functions, sub { OSA::SQL->add_page($date, $stuff, $foo, $bar) };`

Comment: @ysth - LOL... yah, I just realized both right after posting;  though my solution to the second one was slightly different.